# Removing elementsfrom Hashset makes iteration time worse?

Tags: java, runtime, hashset

so my problem is the following: I have a big HashSet of about 9000 elements. I iterate over them rating each element. After finding the ideal one I schedule it and start over again.

The idea is, that each element is removed from the HashSet so iterating over it and rating should become quicker the longer the program runs. The exact opposite happens.

So my question: Is removing elements one by one from a hashset somehow infecting the iteration process in terms of runtime?

```
public double schedule(ScheduleInstance _instance){
    try {
        HashSet<element> Elements= new HashSet<>(); 
        while (Elements.size() > 0) {
            findAndScheduleBestTuppel(Elements);
            removeFoundElement();
            rate(Elements);
        }
        return 0.0;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing more about what these methods do, it's difficult to say.

Comment: You should always name classes starting with a capital letter and variables with a lower case letter. So your `Elements` and `element` names should be `elements` and `Element`.

Comment: I would not expect iteration times to increase. Can you provide some numbers? How much does the time increase. Try removing the other code, just leaving the iterate and remove logic and see what happens.

Comment: You could replace your HashSet with a TreeSet containing a Comparator that already calculates the "best" bringing it to be the first element. This simplifies a lot your iterations and makes the cost of removing and inserting to be O(log(base 2) N)

Comment: I found the problem using jprofiler. As expected, removing objects does not increase the execution time. It was a faulty loop in the logic itself.